# Get range of commits in same branch using git rev-parse

Tags: git

I have a linear history with two branches on it, `dev` and `master`. `master` is always fast-forwardable to `dev`, and there are no other branches. I would like to get all the commits between `dev` and `master` from `git rev-parse`.

For example, my history looks like this (from `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --branches`):

```
* 693dc30 (HEAD, dev) E
* d650d35 D
* 1c4e641 C
* b27ea83 (master) B
* 95fe748 A
...
```

I am currently trying to call

```
git rev-parse master..dev
```

and expecting to get something like

```
693dc30...
d650d35...
1c4e641...
```

Instead I get

```
693dc30...
b27ea83...
^b27ea83...
```

How do I get the full list of commits between the specified selections, and how do I properly interpret the result of `git rev-parse` that I am getting?

I am using Git version 1.7.1. I would prefer to use low-level commands like `rev-parse` for this application rather than the porcelain ones like `log`, but I am open to any solution that works well.

Comment: My impression is that you confuse `git rev-parse` with `git rev-list`. `git rev-list master..dev` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Leon noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357020/get-range-of-commits-in-same-branch-using-git-rev-parse#comment64131530_38357020), the answer is to use `git rev-list`.

Git's revision handling code is ... complicated.  But there is a good mental model you can use:

- There are *revision specifiers*, which are listed in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Except for range notations (`X..Y` and `X...Y` and a few of the more esoteric specifiers like `<rev>^@`), these specify one specific *object*, usually a commit.  A tag name that points to an annotated tag resolves to its annotated-tag-object, though, *unless* you use the `gitrevisions` style suffixes to force Git to "peel" these to commits, or even to trees or blobs.

  The `rev-parse` command works with revision specifiers (plus all the other goodies shoved into it, such as parsing arguments for shell scripts, or showing you where the top level directory is, or testing for a `--bare` repository).
- But then you can select one of these "with ancestry", as I call it.  This only makes sense with commits, or with tag objects that Git can then resolve to commits.  Selecting a commit with ancestry gets you that commit, and its parent commits (usually just one commit but more if it's a merge), and those parent commits' parents—the commit's grandparents—and *their* parents and so on, forever down the line, until you run into the dead-ends at root commits (commits that have no parents).

  The `rev-list` command is what does selection-with-ancestry.  In fact, it *always* does this unless you add `--no-walk` to the arguments.

When you use a range specifier like `X..Y` or `X...Y`, `git rev-parse` does its best to turn these into roughly-equivalent individual commits with prefix `^` if needed.  This actually loses a bit of information: you can't really tell `X...Y` from `X Y ^$(git merge-base X Y)`, for instance,<sup>1</sup> which means you can't be sure which was the left-side revision specifier.  But in general, if you're doing something that needs `rev-list`-style parsing you'll just use `git rev-list` anyway and not have to worry about that; and `git rev-list` has even more markers, such as a prefix `-` for `--boundary`.

(The `rev-list` command is capable of exposing tree and object IDs as well, but you must give it extra flags to make that happen.  It's used by so many Git commands that [`git rev-list`'s documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) is extremely long, and full of specific options like `--bisect`.  One useful thing to realize, though, is that `git log` and `git rev-list` are almost the same command, with different default output formats.  There are a few other subtle differences but they use the same source code to do mostly the same things, and the two front ends are built from a single `builtin/log.c` file.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Most commands don't *need* to, but `git rev-list` itself does, and `git diff` does.  Also, if there are multiple merge bases, `X...Y` will rev-parse to the ID of *X* (no hat prefix) plus the ID of *Y* (no hat prefix) plus the IDs of *all* the merge-bases (all with hat prefixes), since the idea here is to select all commits reachable from either *X* or *Y*, but not from both, hence excluding all their merge-bases and all earlier commits.